# How to declare a constant date in go

Tags: go

I tried to define a constant date like this:

```
const fixed = time.Date(2018, time.January, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, time.UTC)
```

However this does not work because of `const initializer is not a constant`. :(

Although I understand that technically `Date` is a function call, semantically this is a very constant expression.

Is there a way to define a date as a constant?

Comment: How is this question a duplicate? The linked question discussed constant arrays, this one is asking for a constant date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Go doesn't let you define struct constants. What I would suggest you do is to declare const int64 representing your time as a Unix timestamp. Then whenever you need to use it, you can call `time.UnixNano`.